# How to remove header and footer from window.print() without set margin to 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML code with a Table that I want to print using window.print(). I need to remove the headers and footers (The ones that the browsers add automatically, I mean, URL, number of page, etc.) on every page, but I need to keep the margin with an specific size.
This is my CSS:

```
@page { 
    size: auto;
    margin: 5cm 0 5cm 0;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

I need to keep these 5cm because the company I'm working for is using previously letterheaded sheets. How can I remove these headers and footers without modifying my margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`@media print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) query within your css. For example:

```css
@media print {
  thead, tfoot {  
    display: none !important
  }
}
```

> I would wish it could be that easy. I mean, the automatic headers and footers that the browser is creating, that contains the URL, the number of page and other useless (In my situation) data.

Ok, now, I got it. You can try this (should work on Chrome):

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 0mm;
  }

  /* in case @page {margin: 5cm 0 5cm 0;} doesn't work */
  body {
    padding-top: 5cm !important;
    padding-bottom: 5cm !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I mean, the header and footer of the page, not the table. Sorry. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @AxelLeon no, problem. Instead of `thead, tfoot`, you can also apply it to the respective selectors of your page header and footer. e.g. `.page-header { display: none !important; }`

Comment: I would wish it could be that easy. I mean, the automatic headers and footers that the browser is creating, that contains the URL, the number of page and other useless (In my situation) data.

Comment: @AxelLeon I see. Updated my answer. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Oh god, you're amazing. Thank you a lot!