# Hide 'about:blank' while printing a html form of an app which i developed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, printing

I wanna remove the 'about:blank' text that is being printed everytime I try printing a form of an app. Attached is the form(top) where 'about:blank' appears always.

Anything, we could do to remove it? btw, i use javascript to print

function printPageArea(areaID){
``` var printContent = document.getElementById(areaID); var WinPrint = window.open("http://myaddress.com/problem.html"); WinPrint.document.write(printContent.innerHTML); ``your text ```your text `WinPrint.document.close(); WinPrint.focus(); WinPrint.print(); WinPrint.close(); }`

I'm not sure what to do and still exploring. My expectation is to remove about:blank through code

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60909870)? Read the entire answer, since the first part of it refers to something else.